# Divergence of the sum of the reciprocals of the primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I know there are many ways to prove that the sum of the reciprocals of the primes diverges, but does the following argument work?

---

The cardinality of the set of all prime numbers is obviously ${\aleph_0}$. Intuitively we can map each natural number $N$ to a prime number ${p_N}$. Therefore
$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty{\frac{1}{{p_n}}}$$
diverges because
\begin{align}
1 &\mapsto {p_1}\\
2 &\mapsto {p_2}\\
3 &\mapsto {p_3}\\
  &\vdots\\
\end{align}
i.e. it resembles the harmonic series
$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty{\frac{1}{n}}.$$
If it does not work, is there a way to make this argument work?

---

**Edit**: If this argument does not work in general, why does it make intuitive sense for the primes, but not for the reciprocals of the squares?

Comment: Notice that for every $i,$ we have $\dfrac{1}{p_i}<\dfrac{1}{i},$ which doesn't help for the comparison test.

Comment: The convergence of harmonic subseries is related to the density of its terms. See the work of Šalát et al; for instance http://eudml.org/doc/118201.

Comment: The question, "why does it make intuitive sense for the primes," is a question of psychology (specifically, a question of *your* psychology), not of mathematics.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Almost all theorems are motivated by intuition and experience. We are not machines.

Comment: True. But if that was meant as a reply to my comment, I don't see the connection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it doesn’t. If the argument worked, it would prove that $\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac1{n^2}$ diverges, since you could set up a similar correspondence.

Comment: Is there a way to make this argument work?

Comment: @glebovg: Not that I can see: cardinality is just too crude a measure to be very useful here.

Comment: Brian, do you think you can add something regarding my edit?

Comment: It does not "make intuitive sense." It is not that the argument does not work "in general." It just does not work. It so happens that some series diverge (such as $\sum\frac1{p_i}$), but the reason is not that they have infinitely many terms.

Comment: @glebovg: I agree with Andres: it doesn’t make intuitive sense to me. I can often see the thinking behind students’ mistakes, but here I have to admit that can’t see why you feel that it does make intuitive sense.

Comment: So you do not intuitively think that the sum of the reciprocals of the primes diverges, and the sum of the reciprocals of the squares does not?

Comment: @glebovg: I was talking about the argument that you offered, not about the fact itself. But no, I don’t think that it’s intuitively obvious that the sum of the reciprocals of the primes diverges.

Comment: If you want something fun to think about, consider the sum of the reciprocals of those positive integers with no $9$ in their decimal representations. What does your intuition tell you about them?

Comment: @Gerry: Oh, good one!

Comment: @GerryMyerson Do you mean Kempner series? Yes, intuitively it should diverge but it does not.

Comment: I didn't recall that Kempner was associated to that series.

Comment: @Gerry: He seems to have given the first published proof of its convergence; see [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kempner_series). MathWorld uses the name, for whatever that’s worth.